# Why type inference fails with Seq#collect in this case

Tags: scala

The following

```
List(1, 2, 3).collect { x =>
  val dummy = ()
  x match { case _ => x }
}
```

results in

```
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type
                  List(1, 2, 3).collect { x =>
```

but this seemingly identical snippet works as expected:

```
List(1, 2, 3).collect { x =>
  x match { case _ => x }
}
```

It's true that `collect` takes a `PartialFunction`, but the way I see this is that if  `{ x => x match { ... } }` is `PartialFunction` (which must be due to a special case in the compiler because it looks just like a normal function that `throws MatchError`) then `{ x => smth(); x match { ... } }` should also be a `PartialFunction`. (*EDIT: I'm not sure even the first case is inferred to be a `PartialFunction`*)

Comment: And why do you need smth()? Btw, you can take a look at this [article about partial functions in Scala](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#resolvers).

Comment: Actually I need to do `smth -> x match { ... }` so that I wouldn't have to repeat how `smth` is constructed in every `case` of the `match`; alternatively, I can put it in a `val` and reuse in the `case` but that makes out the same; (but the article is about SBT; your clipboard's playing tricks on you :))

Comment: You're welcome.:) 

I don't know exactly what's your use case, but you may try something like this: list.map(x => smth(x)).collect.

E.g.

val list = List("1", "2", "33")
list.map(elem => elem.toInt).collect(_ match {case x: Int if x > 2 => x})

This: a) converts each string into an int (your smth() function), b) collects ints which are >2.

Comment: Sorry, I thanked you prematurely: the link is not what you intended to share; and I don't think the code examples help me; in fact I don't think there's a very compact solution to this :) but that's OK

Comment: The link was actually: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html , sorry about that.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is described in the Scala specification in section [8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](http://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/ScalaReferenceWebTeX.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions).

In short it means that an expression `{x => x match { case ... => ... } }`, which is an anonymous function, is implicitly converted to a `PartialFunction` when a `PartialFunction` is expected, as it is the case for `collect`.

The expression

```
{ x =>
  val dummy = ()
  x match { case _ => x }
}
```

is of different shape, thus it is not implicitly converted. It is treated as type `A => B` because it takes a value of type `A` and its body contains two expressions, namely `val dummy = ()` and `x match { case _ => x }` where the latter produces a value of type `B`

Comment: OK, so this is what I suspected.

Comment: I can't tell whether the spec says this. It says the `{ case => }` block is a PMAF, and it says the case block is "equivalent to" the corresponding func or PF, but never that the func is (as it were transitively) equivalent to the PF.  But the code comment is clear that it intends to do it. And I see that they did work for [vpm] to move this from uncurry to typer. It's not mentioned in the Scala book.

Comment: @som-snytt: I agree, the spec is not completely clear to answer this question definitively. On the other side, that is the case for a lot of things in the spec.